# Programmatically attach two objects with a hinge joint

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ball that is attached to the bottom of a bar with a hinge joint that is swinging back and forth. The hinge joint is on the ball and attaches to the bar. When I tap the screen the hinge joint on the ball is destroyed and depending on the position of the ball will throw it using the built in physics.

I want to collide with another swinging bar and attach to it with a hinge joint. So basically a swinging game for a ball where you swing from bar to bar.

I can destroy the hinge joint just fine. How do I reattach it to the object it has collided with? I have the following:

Attach ball:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class attachBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
        if (collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            print ("COLLISION DETECTED!");
            player.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
        }
    }

}
```

Release ball:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class releaseBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Destroy(player.GetComponent("HingeJoint2D"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed a 2d circle collider on both the ball and the bar it is to collide with. It has a collision but when it does it locks the ball in place. I want it to attach to the bar it has collided with and swing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had the script on the rope originally but I moved it to the ball.

Then I find the gameobject with the tag "Player" to re-attach the hinge joint to the ball.

Then I defined the object that I collided with and place it in the GameObject "rope".

Then I had to define the hinge I added and the rigidbody already attached to the rope.

After setting it as the connectedBody I moved the connected anchor to be on the end of the rope.

And voila. Ball swings on the rope.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class attachBall : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;
public GameObject rope;
public HingeJoint2D hinge;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public bool attached = false;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {

    if (collider.tag == "rope" && !attached) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("collision");
        attached = true;
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        player.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D> ();
        rope = collider.gameObject;
        hinge = player.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
        rb = rope.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        hinge.connectedBody = rb;
        hinge.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(0,-2.5f);

    }

}

}
```